# Can I use window functions in doctrine 2?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, window-functions

```
SELECT invoice.id, 
COUNT(slip.id),
SUM(projected_minutes)  OVER (PARTITION BY task.id) AS projected_minutes
FROM invoice
INNER JOIN task ON task.invoice_id = invoice.id
LEFT JOIN slip ON slip.task_id = task.id
```

The query above is in postgresql, and I want to convert it to DQL, but I cant find any documentation for window functions in DQL, is this natively supported in doctrine or would i have to create a custom dql function for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support for this vendor specific function in Doctrine. Either create a custom DQL function or use Native SQL.

Comment: Was afraid of that, tried searching for custom DQL functions for this, but came up empty, guess I'll write it, just didnt want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: `OVER` isn't exactly vendor specific unless "vendor specific" means "standard SQL that MySQL doesn't understand".

Comment: @muistooshort let me rephrase: "minimum common denominator across vendors" - looks better, no?

Comment: Window functions are part of SQL proper ;)

Comment: came here looking for the same thing. If someone has writting this custom DQL, it would save work.

Comment: @Tom I've added an example in another answer

Answer (score 2):

As asked in one of the comments, I attach my custom string function for COUNT() OVER()

```
<?php

namespace Example\Doctrine\CustomFunctions;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

/**
 * Class CountOverSql
 */
class CountOverSql extends FunctionNode
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $field;

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return "COUNT(".$this->field->dispatch($sqlWalker).") OVER()";
    }

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser): void
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->field = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

and you only need to add this code to your doctrine configuration:

```
$entityManager->getConfiguration()->addCustomStringFunction('count_over', function ($name) use ($c) {
    return new Example\Doctrine\CustomFunctions\CountOverSql($name);
});
```

And to use it, add this code to your select statement:

```
$queryBuilder->select('table_name', 'count_over(table_name.id)');
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different version of window function class. It's more universal, because you can use here any aggregate function + use "Order By" clause in window.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\AggregateExpression;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\OrderByClause;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class Over extends FunctionNode
{
    /** @var AggregateExpression */
    private $functionExpr;

    /** @var OrderByClause */
    private $orderByExpr;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\ASTException
     */
    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker): string
    {
        if (!empty($this->orderByExpr->orderByItems)) {
            return "{$this->functionExpr->dispatch($sqlWalker)} OVER ({$this->orderByExpr->dispatch($sqlWalker)})";
        }

        return "{$this->functionExpr->dispatch($sqlWalker)} OVER ()";
    }

    /**
     * @param Parser $parser
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException
     */
    public function parse(Parser $parser): void
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->functionExpr = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->orderByExpr = $parser->OrderByClause();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$aggregateQueryResult = $this->createQueryBuilder('agg')
      ->select('OVER(sum(agg.quantity), ORDER BY agg.date, agg.id) as aggregated_sum')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension which provide widow functions functionality in Doctrine 2 https://github.com/elshafey/doctrine-window-functions

You can use the extension as following

```php
// configure the extension first
$entityManager->getConfiguration()->addCustomStringFunction(
    'WINDOW',
    \Elshafey\DoctrineExtensions\WindowFunctions\Query\Mysql\Window::class
);

// use your window function formula
SELECT invoice.id, 
COUNT(slip.id),
WINDOW(SUM(projected_minutes))  OVER (PARTITION BY task.id) AS projected_minutes
FROM invoice
INNER JOIN task ON task.invoice_id = invoice.id
LEFT JOIN slip ON slip.task_id = task.id
```