# when I try to write a dql query there is an error for lag & over ( beberlei/DoctrineExtensions )

Tags: doctrine, symfony4, dql, mysql-8.0, doctrine-extensions

I'm trying to convert a MySQL8 query to Doctrine DQL in Symfony4. I used to https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions extensions. But there are still errors.

Query is work well.

```sql
SELECT id, machine_amount, LAG(machine_amount) OVER ( PARTITION BY machine_id ORDER BY id ) AS prevField FROM machine_income
```

**repositoryClass**

```php
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('mi');

$q->select('mi.id, mi.machineAmount');
$q->addSelect('LAG(mi.machineAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY mi.machine ORDER BY mi.id) AS prevField');

return $q->getQuery()->getSQL();
```

**doctrine.yaml**

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                lag: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Lag
                over: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Over
```

**DQL out**

```
SELECT mi.id, mi.machineAmount, LAG(mi.machineAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY mi.machine ORDER BY mi.id) AS prevField FROM App\Entity\MachineIncome mi
```

When I try to create getSQL() I saw error.

**error**

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 59: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '('
```

any help?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from [the implementation](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v1.2.9/src/Query/Mysql/Over.php), this extension only supports the following syntax:

```
OVER( arithmeticExpression [, order by clause])
```

So, no `PARTITION BY`.
You probably need something like this:
https://github.com/elshafey/doctrine-window-functions

Or pick from the answers to this other question:
[Can I use window functions in doctrine 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646912/can-i-use-window-functions-in-doctrine-2)